# Using MySQL variable in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

How to properly use MySQL variable in WHERE clause? Instead of column1, column2, column3 I've got massive queries that is why I think it's better to use variables for that. Don't know what I'm doing wrong!

```
SELECT 
@TEST:= CASE 
    WHEN column1=1 THEN 'ONE'
    WHEN column1=2 THEN 'TWO'
    WHEN column1=2 THEN 'THREE'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
END AS test
FROM 
    table1
WHERE
    @TEST= 'ONE'
```

Comment: And we dont know what you want to achive.  Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is wrong with current query? Any error, wrong result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I guessed correctly, you want to avoid repeating yourself:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN column1=1 THEN 'ONE'
    WHEN column1=2 THEN 'TWO'
    WHEN column1=2 THEN 'THREE'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
END AS test
FROM table1
WHERE CASE 
    WHEN column1=1 THEN 'ONE'
    WHEN column1=2 THEN 'TWO'
    WHEN column1=2 THEN 'THREE'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
END = 'ONE';
```

... but the obvious approach triggers an error:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN column1=1 THEN 'ONE'
    WHEN column1=2 THEN 'TWO'
    WHEN column1=2 THEN 'THREE'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
END AS test
FROM table1
WHERE test = 'ONE';
```

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'test' in 'where clause'

... so you've figured out you could use variables as in any other programming language.

For good or bad, SQL is not a programming language (it's a *query* language) and variables don't behave this way. Generally speaking, you cannot use variables to replace code fragments. And using them to store values (as in your example) is pretty risky, as [the manual warns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html):

> other than in `SET` statements you should never assign a value to a
>   user variable and read the value within the same statement. [...] For
>   other statements, such as `SELECT`, **you might get the results you
>   expect, but this is not guaranteed**.

In this situation, repeating the entire expression is probably the only sensible way to go. If the actual code is huge and difficult to maintain, you can always generate your SQL dynamically in your client language (PHP, Java, whatever...). MySQL itself has some [dynamic SQL features](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) but they aren't as handy.

In specific circumstances, you could also play with subqueries, but be warned that performance *may* sometimes suffer:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN column1=1 THEN 'ONE'
        WHEN column1=2 THEN 'TWO'
        WHEN column1=2 THEN 'THREE'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS test
    FROM table1
) t
WHERE test = 'ONE';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `WHERE` is <strike>evaluated</strike> applied before `SELECT` which means your query isn't possible at all that way (not 100% sure tho).

You can do it this way which is essentially the same:

```
SELECT 
    column1 AS TEST
FROM 
    table1
WHERE
    (column1 = 1 AND ONE = 'ONE')
OR  (column1 = 2 AND TWO = 'ONE')
OR  (column1 = 3 AND THREE = 'ONE')
OR  Unknown = 'ONE'
```

Comment: Thanks but your approach won't work in my case...You see instead of `column1`, `column2`, `column3` I've got massive queries that is why I think it's better to use variables for that. But I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Maybe your whole database scheme is not normalized then.